# Some small error in outputting fibonacci numbers

Tags: c#, fibonacci

The output should be like 1 1 2 3 5 etc, not like 1 2 3 5 8. So it misses the first calculation, otherwise, it works perfectly.

Our example on the homework said it should include the both 1's. Variables are in finnish, i saw no reason to change them into english since this is just a homework.

```
int eka = 0, toka = 1, tulo, toisto = 1;

WriteLine("Kuinka monta numeroa haluat? ");
int vaatimus = int.Parse(ReadLine());

while (toisto ++ <= vaatimus)
    {
    tulo = eka + toka;

    WriteLine(tulo);

    eka = toka;
    toka = tulo;
}
ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is a basic problem with your logic. Try debugging your program first.

Comment: put `WriteLine(toka);` before the while loop

Comment: Step through the program with your debugger and the solution will become apparent.

Comment: @SonerGönül it is meaningful, but finnish

Comment: @AntiHeadshot Okey, that was _meaningfull_.

Comment: @Esa: you're incrementing `toisto` but doing nothing with it after. Strongly suggest you sit down, look at what is going on line-by-line, and it'll be clear that you have too many variables going on at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `WriteLine`:

```
int eka = 0, toka = 1;
int vaatimus;
var toisto = 1;

WriteLine("Kuinka monta numeroa haluat? ");
var parseResult = int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out vaatimus);

if (parseResult)
{
  WriteLine(toisto);
  while (toisto++ <= vaatimus)
  {
    var tulo = eka + toka;

    WriteLine(tulo);

    eka = toka;
    toka = tulo;
  }
}
else
{
    WriteLine("ErrorMessage!");
}

ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hhmm, we haven't gone this far yet on your classes. 
var-command is not familiar with me, i understand it declares a new variable but not sure what it is, and then that out-command also is unknown. I'll look them up on google.

Just went over the while, if and for loops on our class, and these are those exercises. 

I'll try this and look up those unfamiliar commands. Thank you.

Comment: Although it yields the same result, I think it would be more semantically correct to use `WriteLine(toka)` instaed of `WriteLine(toisto)`